Webm file downloaded from user's microphone does not have duration metadata
I am trying to record the user's microphone, and then send it to an API.
I did the code for the recording, and it works well, but when I send it to the API, it says that it does not have a duration.
So I decided to download the audio on localhost and see if that is true, and well, it is true.
My question is, is there a way to record the user's microphone with the duration metadata headers? Or is there a way to attach the duration on that recorded blob/file?
Here is what I have so far:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Record 10s from user microphone</title>
</head>

<body>

    <script>

        const constraints = { audio: true };

        navigator.mediaDevices
            .getUserMedia(constraints)
            .then((stream) => {
                const innerMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {
                    mimeType: "audio/webm",
                    bitsPerSecond: 128000,
                    audioBitrateMode: "constant",
                });

                const chunks = [];

                innerMediaRecorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", (e) => {
                    chunks.push(e.data);
                });

                innerMediaRecorder.addEventListener("stop", () => {
                    const innerFileName = "test.webm";
                    const innerFiles = [
                        new File(chunks, innerFileName, { type: "audio/webm; codecs=opus;" })
                    ]
                    const blob = new Blob(chunks, { type: "audio/webm; codecs=opus;" });;
                    const audioURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    const downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
                    downloadLink.style.display = "none";
                    downloadLink.href = audioURL;
                    downloadLink.download = innerFileName;
                    document.body.insertAdjacentElement("beforeend", downloadLink);
                    downloadLink.click();
                    downloadLink.remove();
                });

                innerMediaRecorder.start();

                setTimeout(() => {
                    innerMediaRecorder.stop();
                }, 10000);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.error(`The following error occurred: ${err}`);
            });
    </script>
</body>

</html>

I know I can get the duration of the recorded blob with the following:
blob.arrayBuffer().then(arrayBuffer => {
    const audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
    audioContext.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer).then(audioBuffer => {
        console.log('Duration:', audioBuffer.duration);
    });
})

But how do I attach this to the downloaded file?
